# Plotting a section of an hemisphere

Tags: plotting

I'm writing a little package in Mathematica for geology where a particular stone may be approximated as an hemisphere. Anyway this is a rough estimation because a real hemisphere has its height as loong as its radius. Instead, a reservoir stone (for an hydrocarbon) has often a form of a section of an hemisphere, its height is lower than the radius. For example, I can have an hemisphere with radius long 5 km and height of only 3 km and I can plot it like that:

```
semisfera[x_, y_, raggio_] := Sqrt[raggio^2 - (x - raggio)^2 - (y - raggio)^2];
 plotsemisfera = Plot3D[semisfera[x, y, raggioSfera], {x, 0, 2  raggioSfera}, {y, 0, 2  raggioSfera}, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"lunghezza km" , "larghezza km","profondità km"}, PlotLabel ->  Style[Framed["Referenced Theorical Hemisphere"], 22, Black]]
```

and I get the following graphic:
[image]

you'll agree with me that is a section of ah hemisphere without the top part, won't you?

Sometimes it may happen that the height is << radius.
In my case, my geology student worked on a stone with radius of 5km and an height of only 0.2 km.
If I try to plot this as I've done before, I get a very awful graphic, here:

[image]

So, I'd just like to know if there is a way to plot a more precise graphic, without all that irregular part at the base of the hemisphere.

The centre of the "hemisphere" should be in  = <0,0>

Maybe it could be something like that:
http://uploadpie.com/eAVvq

but I really don't understand why for low values of the height the base of the hemisphere is so jagged!

How can I plot that? Thank you

Comment: `SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/5}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: Need more info. Do you want a 3D plot or a 3D graphic? Do you want it defined in terms of radius and height? Is center at the origin OK, or do you want to position the "stone" arbitrarily?

Comment: Ehm, it's a bit difficult to understand. I've tried what you've written but what I meant was a section of a hemisphere without the top...it should look like a conic section, not of a cone but of an hemisphere. The underneath part, not the top one. is it a bir clearer? :S

Comment: The stone can be put in the centre <0,0> anyway it's not very important. And yes, I'd need a 3D graphic depending on radius and height.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't understand what you're saying...I have some difficulty in understanding these graphic routine...what do you mean?

Comment: @LoryLory `SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], Pi/5, Pi/2}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi},   AspectRatio -> Automatic]`. It is unclear what you are asking, please provide an image of the object you are looking for.

Comment: you can see ax example here http://uploadpie.com/ln1NU it's a trunc of a semisphere where the upper part is missing at a certain height. The problem of this example is that it plots good only when the heigth is similar to the radius. If I try to plot with a big difference between the two (radius = 5 and height = 0.2) it plots a mess.

Comment: @LoryLory Here are some ideas to get this question reopened so it can be answered: Share the code you used for that plot, put the image in the question, share a photo of the stone if you have it and look over your description in the question and see again if you can improve, perhaps by clarifying some of the misconceptions in the comments.

Comment: Ok, I've added all details as possibile and some pictures of the situation. What will you say?

Comment: @Pickett done!is it better now?

Comment: @LoryLory Yes, much better. I've voted to reopen it and someone else has too, so hopefully in a while it will be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit

I now have a better understanding of what you are looking for.

To get plot centered at the origin defined in terms of the radius and height, then you can use [`SphericalPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) as Kuba suggested. It would go like this.

```
theta[r_, h_] /; 0 < h < r := π/2. - ArcTan[Sqrt[r^2 - h^2], h]
With[{r = 5, h = 3, zScale = .3}, 
  SphericalPlot3D[r, {θ, theta[r, h], π/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, zScale}]]
```

[image: spherical-sect-1]

Note the use of a parameter to scale z-axis. It is set to `h/(2 r)` in the above plot. This gives true proportions.

In the extreme of `r = 5` and `h = .2`, `zScale` will need to be adjusted to give a reasonable looking plot, which is going to look very much like a cylinder.

```
With[{r = 5, h = .2, zScale = .25}, 
  SphericalPlot3D[r, {θ, theta[r, h], π/2.}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, zScale}]]
```

[image: spherical-sect-2]

Comment: The stone can be put in the centre <0,0> anyway it's not very important. And yes, I'd need a 3D graphic depending on radius and height.

Comment: Thank you mate! Forgive for my brief question today but I was very busy in two projects...I've been too short. Sorry! Thank you very much!

Comment: ps: forgive me if I can't mark your answer as useful but I havent't 15 points of reputation yet

Answer (score 5):

The ragged edges were caused by the fact that the parametrization of the surface in terms of height over the equatorial plane is singular at the equator, as you can also see in the increased distance between mesh lines on the plotted surface. So the main part of the solution is to choose a better parametrization, and the most common one is of course some variation of spherical coordinates.

Here is a completely different approach which also uses an angle to parametrize the surface, but should yield a more reusable and render-friendly object that can be displayed in `Graphics3D`.

It uses the fact that `Tube` can be provided not just with a list of points on which it is centered, but also accepts a second argument that contains a list of *diameters*. I use this to draw the shell. `Tube` is therefore a quick and simple way to define rotationally symmetric shapes without using one of the `Plot3D` family commands.

```
Clear[pebble];
pebble[h_, n_: 40] := {
  CapForm["Butt"],
  Apply[Tube,
   Transpose[
    Table[
     {{0, 0, Sin[θ]}, Cos[θ]},
     {θ, 0, ArcSin[h], Pi/(2 n)}]]]
  }

Graphics3D[{Lighter[Brown], pebble[.7]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: pebble1]

```
Graphics3D[{Lighter[Brown], Table[
   Translate[
    Rotate[Scale[ pebble[.1 i], RandomReal[{.1, 1.5}]], 
     i Pi/10, {0, 1, 0}], {2 i, i, 0}], {i, 1, 10}]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

[image: pebbles]

The function `pebble` has only one required argument: the height from the equator, assumed to be between `0` and `1`. So it's basically the aspect ratio, and in the second plot I show how to adjust the overall size using `Scale` in `Graphics3D`. The second optional argument to `pebble` is the resolution with which the surface is drawn, given in terms of the number of latitude divisions.

Comment: Thank you! This is very interesting...I'm afraid one will never know enough about plotting in mathematica. I'll try your suggest and to put it in my project. Thank you a lot! ps: forgive me if I can't mark your answer as useful but I havent't 15 points of reputation yet