# Overlapping Spheres with a Shared Blank Region

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, color

We have two similar overlapped spheres in a way that the distance between their centers is smaller than the sum of their radius (2R>a). As I show here:

[image]

Also, we want to draw them in a such way that the overlapped (shared) region be blank and the each sphere has distinct color. However we drawn it by another software (as above) but we don't know how we can use of *Mathematica* for this aim!?

Comment: Wait, did you want disks, or actual spheres?

Comment: Actually, two spheres  with the transparent colors which the internal realms can be viewed , but here I drawn their Cross Sections. Although the cross section will be desired but the preference is with  spheres.

Comment: I don't have *Mathematica* with me, but try this: `With[{c1 = {-2/3, 0, 0}, r1 = 1, c2 = {2/3, 0, 0}, r2 = 1}, Show[RegionPlot3D[Norm[{x, y, z} - c1] < r1 && Norm[{x, y, z} - c2] > r2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Pink, Opacity[2/3]]], RegionPlot3D[Norm[{x, y, z} - c1] > r1 && Norm[{x, y, z} - c2] < r2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[2/3]]], BoxRatios -> Automatic]]`.

Comment: Thankx I tired it but, the spheres are not so uniform and have sharp edges in some places on their environments. Also, in the touch region they are not so well connected

Comment: Then increase the setting of `PlotPoints`; say, `PlotPoints -> 75`.

Comment: Ok, it has been so good, Thanxxxxx, is it possible to tell a cross section contained just circles (not spheres) with the blank shared region?

Comment: You merely use the 2D analog of what I did; use `RegionPlot[]` instead of `RegionPlot3D[]`, and modify the other parts of the code suitably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternative to `RegionPlot` that potentially produces higher quality: it's based on `Tube` with varying radius, as I also used [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45612/245):

```
With[
 {a = 1, R = .7, n = 40, xMax = 1.5},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[
    {CapForm[None],
     {Opacity[.5], Pink,
        #, Cyan,
        GeometricTransformation[#, {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
        } &[
      Tube @@
       Transpose[
        Table[
           {{-R Cos[θ] - a/2, 0, 0}, R Sin[θ]},
           {θ, 0, #, #/n}] &[ArcCos[-a/2/R]]
        ]
      ],
     {Opacity[1], Glow[White],
        #,
        GeometricTransformation[#, {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
        } &[
      Tube @@
       Transpose[
        Table[
           {{-R Cos[θ] - a/2, 0, 0}, R Sin[θ]},
           {θ, #, Pi, (Pi - #)/n}] &[ArcCos[-a/2/R]]
        ]
      ]
     }, RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}]],
   Lighting -> "Neutral", Background -> Black,
   Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{-xMax, xMax}, {-xMax, xMax}, {-xMax, xMax}}],
  {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]
 ]
```

[image: soheres]

To make the white region of intersection stand out, I made it solid and glowing, while the enclosing spheres are translucent.

Using `Tube` here seemed appropriate because the geometry has overall cylindrical symmetry, and tubes can have a variable radius that in this case is chosen to vary as the cylindrical radial distance from the x axis for each spherical shell portion.

Comment: It is wonderful! tanxxxxx.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html), in which spheres are plotted and then sliced off using the option [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html).

It's not clear to me how you intend to have the inner regions "blank" as they are occluded, but the options to [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) let you vary the appearance.

```
 outerSphere[sphereCenter_: {0, 0, 0}, regionLimit_: 0.6, color_, opacity_] := Module[
   {x = sphereCenter[[1]], y = sphereCenter[[2]], 
    z = sphereCenter[[3]]},
   ParametricPlot3D[
     {x + Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], y + Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ], 
      z + Sin[θ]},
     {θ, -π, π},
     {ϕ, -π/2, π/2},
     Mesh -> None,
     PlotStyle -> {color, Opacity[opacity]},
     RegionFunction -> (#2 < regionLimit &)]
    ];

innerSphere[sphereCenter_: {0, 0, 0}, regionLimit_: 0.6, color_, opacity_, boundaryOn_] := Module[
   {x = sphereCenter[[1]], y = sphereCenter[[2]], 
    z = sphereCenter[[3]]},
   ParametricPlot3D[
     {x + Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], y + Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ], 
      z + Sin[θ]},
     {θ, -π, π},
     {ϕ, -π/2, π/2},
     Mesh -> None,
     PlotStyle -> {color, Opacity[opacity]},
     BoundaryStyle -> Directive[If[boundaryOn == False, Opacity[0]], Thick, Red],
    RegionFunction -> (#2 > regionLimit &)]
   ];

Show[
  {outerSphere[{0, 0, 0}, .7, Green, 0.1],
   innerSphere[{0, 0, 0}, .7, Yellow, 0.6, True],
   innerSphere[{0, 1.4, 0}, .7, Blue, 0.1, False],
   outerSphere[{0, 1.4, 0}, .7, Yellow, 0.6]},
  ViewPoint -> {3, .5, 1},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Axes -> None,
  Boxed -> False]
```

> [image]