# Plotting 3D Intersections

Tags: plotting, intersection

I'm trying to plot the intersections of four spheres. I've got the spheres plotted using:

```
ContourPlot3D[{(-9.2877 - x)^2 + (9.3049 - y)^2 + (5436354.04 - z)^2 == 21496269.296^2,
(20.40241 - x)^2 + (204.918 - y)^2 + (23272267.679 - z)^2 == 20095995.0541^2,
(-39.29329 - x)^2 + (282.248 - y)^2 + (20240909.994 - z)^2 == 22488938.185^2, 
(8.341136 - x)^2 + (48.1826 - y)^2 + (23018246.984 - z)^2 == 19410828.319^2},
{x, -20000000, 20000000}, {y, -20000000, 30000000}, {z, -20000000, 40000000},
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

Is there a simple way to find the intersections and plot those or highlight them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [82473](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82470/overlapping-spheres-with-a-shared-blank-region/82473)

Comment: Four spheres in 3D will not in general have a common point of intersection, and in particular, yours don't.  Do you want the set of intersections of all six pairs of spheres (a set of circles)?  The set of intersections of all four triplets of spheres (a set of points)?  Something else entirely?

Comment: I thought they might not. I'm looking at graphing pseudoranges from GPS satellites. Ideally if the pseudoranges were the geometric ranges there would be a point of intersection. However, there are errors that leads to either more overlap or less overlap of the spheres. Getting the set of intersections of the pairs of spheres would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering your GPS-inspired goal, here's an approach which visualizes a least-squares solution to distances from sphere shells, and the corrected standard deviation as size of the red sphere:

```
Module[{spheres, sol},
 spheres = {
   Sphere[{-9.2877, 9.3049, 5436354.04}, 21496269.296], 
   Sphere[{20.40241, 204.918, 23272267.679}, 20095995.0541], 
   Sphere[{-39.29329, 282.248, 20240909.994}, 22488938.185], 
   Sphere[{8.341136, 48.1826, 23018246.984}, 19410828.319]};
 sol = Sphere[{x, y, z} /. #2, Sqrt[#1/(Length[spheres] - 1)]] & @@ 
   Minimize[
    Total[RegionDistance[#, {x, y, z}]^2 & /@ spheres], {x, y, z}, Reals];
 Graphics3D[{
   Opacity[0.5], spheres,
   Opacity[1], Red, sol}]]
```

[image]

This solution requires v10 due to its use of geometric regions functionality.

Comment: Wow that's great, thanks! I'm getting a couple of issues running 10.1: `Minimize::ivar : 99999.985 is not a valid variable` and `ReplaceAll::reps : {100000.,100000.,100000.} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing`

Comment: @DavidM Have you defined variables `x`, `y` or `z` earlier on your session? Restarting your kernel might help.

Comment: Restarting the kernel fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean the intersection of the regions enclosed by the spheres?

```
RegionPlot3D[And @@ {
(-9.2877 - x)^2 + (9.3049 - y)^2 + (5436354.04 - z)^2 <= 21496269.296^2,
(20.40241 - x)^2 + (204.918 - y)^2 + (23272267.679 - z)^2 <= 20095995.0541^2,
(-39.29329 - x)^2 + (282.248 - y)^2 + (20240909.994 - z)^2 <= 22488938.185^2,
(8.341136 - x)^2 + (48.1826 - y)^2 + (23018246.984 - z)^2 <= 19410828.319^2},
{x, -20000000, 20000000}, {y, -20000000, 30000000}, {z, -20000000, 40000000},
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think that will do quite well. For some reason though it's not showing up in Mathematica for me. I'm just getting an empty bounding box

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually looking for the pairwise intersections of the spheres, here's some code that does the trick.  First, let's define the set of equations:

```
eqns = {(-9.2877 - x)^2 + (9.3049 - y)^2 + (5436354.04 - z)^2 == 21496269.296^2, 
        (20.40241 - x)^2 + (204.918 - y)^2 + (23272267.679 - z)^2 ==  20095995.0541^2, 
        (-39.29329 - x)^2 + (282.248 - y)^2 + (20240909.994 - z)^2 == 22488938.185^2, 
        (8.341136 - x)^2 + (48.1826 - y)^2 + (23018246.984 - z)^2 == 19410828.319^2};
```

We can use `Reduce` to find out whether these equations have a solution over the reals:

```
Reduce[eqns, Reals]

(* False *)
```

So no common solution to these over the real numbers.  Similarly, we can try to see if the triplets of spheres have any common intersections:

```
Reduce[#, Reals]& /@ Subsets[eqns, {3}]

(* {False, False, False, False} *)
```

So no luck there, either.  Let's go to the pairwise intersections of the spheres:

```
intersections = Reduce[#, Reals]& /@ Subsets[eqns, {2}];
```

This yields a set of inequalities & equalities, of which two are identically `False` (i.e., the spheres don't intersect at all) and the rest of which are non-trivial.  So there are pair-wise intersections of these four spheres.

Actually plotting them is trickier.  Mathematica is pretty crap at dealing with implicit curves in 3D, so we have to massage the data into a form where it can be fed into `ParametricPlot3D`.  Basically, we discard the first and last points of each element of `intersections` (which are always single points);  extract the valid regions of `z`, along with `x` and `y` as functions of `z`;  and then feed these data into `ParametricPlot3D`.  The code is pretty ugly, and I'm sure it could be improved:

```
intersections = Reduce[#, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True] & /@ Subsets[eqns, {2}];
paramcurves[inters0_] := 
 Module[{inters = inters0, zranges, xyfns, plotdata},
   inters = Drop[Drop[inters, 1], -1];
   zranges = ({z, First[Minimize[{z, First[#]}, z]], First[Maximize[{z, First[#]}, z]]} & /@ inters) /. Or -> List;
   xyfns = (({x, y} /. {ToRules[Drop[#, 1]]}) & /@ inters) /. Or -> List;
   plotdata = Table[{xyfns[[i]], zranges[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[zranges]}];
   ParametricPlot3D[Append[Evaluate[#[[1, 1]]], z], Evaluate[#[[2]]],  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}] & /@ plotdata
 ]
intersections = DeleteCases[intersections, False];
curves = paramcurves /@ intersections;
Show[contplot, Flatten[curves], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: "pretty crap at dealing with implicit curves in 3D" - but have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968)?

Comment: I had not in fact seen that, and it's pretty useful;  the top-rated answer there could easily be adapted to the present case.

Answer (score 0):

**Interpreation as suggested by the use of ContourPlot3D as surfaces:**

```
s1 = Sphere[{-9.2877, 9.3049, 5436354.04}, 21496269.296]; s2 = 
 Sphere[{20.40241, 204.918, 23272267.679}, 20095995.0541]; s3 = 
 Sphere[{-39.29329, 282.248, 20240909.994}, 22488938.185]; s4 = 
 Sphere[{8.341136, 48.1826, 23018246.984}, 19410828.319];
spheres = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
```

**Table of the pairwise intersection of the spheres:**

```
bore = Table[
   If[i != j, RegionIntersection[spheres[[i]], spheres[[j]]], 
    Nothing], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];

Region /@ (Flatten@bore)
```

[image: table of the pairwise intersection of the spheres]

**All intersections of the pairwise intersections of the spheres in a Region:**

```
RegionUnion@(Flatten@bore);

Region[%]
```

[image: RegionUnion of the intersection of the spheres pairwise]

This result can be seen if the spheres are displayed transparent:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Yellow, s1, Opacity[0.1], LightYellow, s2, 
  Opacity[0.1], LightYellow, s3, Opacity[0.1], LightYellow, s4}]
```

[image: The spheres over each other transparent]

both 3D representations are the same axis directed up.