# Why is this plot drawn so poorly? Can I draw a better image?

Tags: plotting

The function
`y = 4 - 4 ( (1 - x^4)^(1/4) )`
is defined on the interval `(-1, 1)` but as you can see on the image rendered with Mathematika 12  the ends of the curve don't touch `y = 4` line, however they must do. How do I get a better drawing?
[image: y = 4 - 4 ( (1 - x^4)^(1/4) )]

```
Plot[{{4 - 4 ((1 - x^4)^(1/4))}, {4}}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Comment: You can always enlarge the interval, say from -1.5 to 1.5.

Comment: Please post the code you used to make this plot

Comment: You can use the `PlotRange` option.

Comment: `Plot[{4,4-4((1-x^4)^(1/4))},{x,-1,1},PlotRange->{0,4},PlotPoints->1000]`

Comment: Similar problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173397/unexpected-holes-in-contourplot3d

Comment: The interval -1.5 to 1.5 does not save the day. :)

Comment: It is really funny, I would never expect. Setting `{x, -1.5, 1.5}` even makes "BoundaryOffset" inoperative!

Answer (score 17):

By default, there is a very slight [offset from the boundary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173431/4999) in the sample points used.

```
Plot[{4 - 4 ((1 - x^4)^(1/4)), 4}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 Method -> "BoundaryOffset" -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: It's funny, if I set `{x, -1.5, 1.5}` your method stops working.

Comment: @yarchik Seems predictable to me....Discrete sampling has its drawbacks. I think one would stick to the domain `{x, -1, 1}` since experience teaches going outside like  `{x, -1.5, 1.5}` is a mistake in functions like `Sqrt[]` ([1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/plotting-a-section-of-an-hemisphere), [2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135551/contourplot3d-quality-very-poor)) and other even roots; and the problem with dancing on the edge of the domain is somewhat obvious after a little thought.

Answer (score 8):

How about a [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) ?

```
ContourPlot[
           {
              y == 4
            , y == 4 - 4 ((1 - x^4)^(1/4))
           }
          , {x, -1, 1}
          , {y, -1, 5}
          , PlotPoints -> 200
          , AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio
          , GridLines -> Automatic
  ]
```

[image]